# Escaped quotes in received HTML form values

Tags: php, html, input, encoding, escaping

Please have a look at the [SSCCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) below. It's a simple HTML form with a text field and a text area, both containing a string with quotes and tags.

When the form is submitted, the received values are encoded (using `htmlentities`), decoded (using `html_entity_decode`), and then compared with the original value (see invocations of the `evaluate` method in the SSCCE).

On my *local* server these values are equal. But on the *remote* server they are not, instead all quotes are escaped, i.e. `\'` and `\"` are received.

Why is this? Is it a PHP version issue? (local: 5.4.9, remote: 5.3.18)

Furthermore, the remote server cannot handle umlauts (like ä, ö, ü), although I specified UTF-8 in the HTML head. Why?

Here is the SSCCE:

```
<?php // sscce.php

    function encode($string)
    {
        return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    function decode($string)
    {
        return html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    function evaluate($string1, $string2)
    {
        echo (strcmp($string1, $string2) == 0) ? 'OK' : 'FAIL: ' . $string2;
    }

    $value = <<<'EOT'
<p>'a' & "b"</p>
EOT;

    $encodedValue = encode($value);

    $encodedReceivedValueTF = encode(isset($_GET['submit']) ? $_GET['tf'] : '');
    $encodedReceivedValueTA = encode(isset($_GET['submit']) ? $_GET['ta'] : '');

    $decodedReceivedValueTF = decode($encodedReceivedValueTF);
    $decodedReceivedValueTA = decode($encodedReceivedValueTA);

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>', PHP_EOL;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>SSCCE</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>PHP: <?php echo phpversion(); ?></h2>
        <h2>Test Values</h2>
        <form action="sscce.php" method="get">
            <div><input id="tf" name="tf" type="text" size="50" value="<?php echo $encodedValue; ?>" /></div>
            <div><textarea id="ta" name="ta" rows="1" cols="50"><?php echo $encodedValue; ?></textarea></div>
            <div><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Perform Test!" /></div>
            <div><a href="sscce.php">Reset</a></div>
        </form>

        <h2>Encoded Values</h2>
        <div>Text Field: <?php echo evaluate($encodedValue, $encodedReceivedValueTF); ?></div>
        <div>Text Area: <?php echo evaluate($encodedValue, $encodedReceivedValueTA); ?></div>

        <h2>Decoded Received Values</h2>
        <div>Text Field: <?php echo evaluate($value, $decodedReceivedValueTF); ?></div>
        <div>Text Area: <?php echo evaluate($value, $decodedReceivedValueTA); ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To deactivate escaped quotes: [disable PHP's magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)
- To handle umlauts: Specify UTF-8 encoding in `htmlentities()`